# Thunderbird contacts sync

Tags: synchronization, thunderbird

i work in a small office company and using thunderbird on all workstations, i've been searching for a solution of an address book that can be synced around the office and on an web-based application that may have the option to sync to other devices such as Android/iphone.

I tried SoGo, but it's pretty outdated since the rapid releases of TB, tried LDAP but can't be edited, tried SyncKobalt but didn't work well, tried vtiger with no great results.

The only thing that work's pretty well is Zindus + Google Contacts, the big downside is that the information is stored on the google servers rather then local.

Is anyone having a real life working solution that uses Thunderbird, or should i switch to Outlook or another client that actually offers some sync support ?

Answer (score 0):

try  [thunderbird sync](http://www.thunderbirdsync.com)

Comment: As far as i can see that's basically Zindus + Google Contacts, and i would love a local solution.